# I am trying to do the Horizontal arrangement of cards in asp dot net project

Tags: asp.net, razor, .net-core

I am working on one project and got some brain storming question.
I am trying to do the card in aspdotnet core application in .cshtml file.
but by default the cards are arrange in vertical manner. I want them into the horizontal manner. What should I do for it.?

The folowing is the code for index.cshtml file:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div class="card border-warning card-columns" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EquipmentName) : </strong>
        <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EquipmentName)</p>

        <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EquipmentSetValueTemp) : </strong>
        <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EquipmentSetValueTemp)</p>

        <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EquipmentProcessValueTemp) : </strong>
        <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EquipmentProcessValueTemp)</p>
        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.EquipmentId" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a>
        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.EquipmentId" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

I got An answer.
Just add the style like display:inlin-block;
and delete the card-columns form class name.

New index.cshtml file :

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="card border-warning" style="width: 18rem; display:inline-block;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EquipmentName) : </strong>
            <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EquipmentName)</p>

            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EquipmentSetValueTemp) : </strong>
            <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EquipmentSetValueTemp)</p>

            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EquipmentProcessValueTemp) : </strong>
            <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EquipmentProcessValueTemp)</p>
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.EquipmentId" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a>
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.EquipmentId" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

[image: Result Image]

Answer (score 0):

Use following style in inline CSS

```
style="width: 18rem;display:inline-block; margin:10px"
```